# Moq failed for SetupSet/VerifySet

Tags: c#, interface, installation, moq, verify

I'm new to Moq and I have this test function:

```
using Moq;
using Xunit;

namespace MyTest
{
    public class UseMoq
    {
        public interface IFoo
        {
            string Name { get; set; }
        }
        [Fact]
        public static void UseMock()
        {
            var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
            mock.SetupSet(foo => foo.Name = "foo");
            mock.VerifySet(foo => foo.Name = "foo");
        }
    }
}
```

It runs and fail, saying:

```
Message: 
    Moq.MockException : 
    Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: foo => foo.Name = "foo"

    Performed invocations:

    Mock<UseMoq.IFoo:1> (foo):
    No invocations performed.

Stack Trace: 
    Mock.Verify(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Times times, String failMessage)
    Mock.VerifySet(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Times times, String failMessage)
    Mock`1.VerifySet(Action`1 setterExpression)
    ... ...
```

What does this error message actually mean, and how to fix it?

Comment: You are calling verify on a mocked member that has not been invoked. That is why you get the error in your shown example. The `Verify*` methods as usually called in the *Assert* phase of the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mocking framework is behaving as designed.

You are calling verify on a mocked member that has not been invoked. That is why you get the error in your shown example.

```
mock.SetupSet(foo => foo.Name = "foo"); //<--Setup expectation
mock.VerifySet(foo => foo.Name = "foo"); //<--Verify expectation
```

Because the setup tells mocking framework to expect certain behavior but

> No invocations performed.

as stated by the failure message

> Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: foo => foo.Name = "foo"

That said, the `Verify*` methods as usually called in the *Assert* phase of a test case. By then the mock would be been used as a dependency by some subject under test and the mocked member invokes as expected while exercising the subject under test.

```
//Arrange

//...initialize mock...

mock.SetupSet(foo => foo.Name = "foo"); //<--Setup expectation

//Act
//...subject under test uses mock

//Assert
mock.VerifySet(foo => foo.Name = "foo"); //<--Verify expectation
```

Review the [MOQ Quickstart: Verification](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#verification) for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

It fails because you don't have an implementation, to test the change in property value you must change it through the implementation, not the interface

maybe the example helps you

```
public class UseMoq
{
    public interface IFoo
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Foo : IFoo
    {
        private readonly IFoo _foo;

        public Foo(IFoo foo)
        {
            _foo = foo;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string GetName()
        {
            return _foo.Name;
        }

        public void SetName(string name)
        {
            _foo.Name = name;
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public static void UseMock()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
        mock.SetupGet(x => x.Name).Returns("foo");

        var fooName = new Foo(mock.Object).GetName();

        mock.VerifyGet(m => m.Name, Times.Once);



        /*
         * Another TestMethod

         */

        new Foo(mock.Object).SetName("new Foo Name");

        mock.VerifySet(m => m.Name = "new Foo Name",Times.Once);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't get your point: mock class is used to implement methods/property which avoid us from the burden of writing implement classes for tests. So if there a way we can just moq, please? Thanks again.